# Ruby Gems Not Installing on Amazon EC2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2

I have an amazon ec2 server running and I want to install ruby on rails on it. But when I type  `sudo gem install rails`, it doesn't work. It keeps waiting. I waited for 30 min. trying to see what was wrong. This is what I got after typing in `sudo gem install rails -V`:

```
GET http://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz
302 Moved Temporarily
GET http://production.s3.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz
304 Not Modified
GET http://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz
302 Moved Temporarily
GET http://production.s3.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz
304 Not Modified
GET http://rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/rack-test-0.6.1.gemspec.rz
302 Moved Temporarily
GET http://production.cf.rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/rack-test-0.6.1.gemspec.rz
200 OK
GET http://rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/rack-test-0.6.2.gemspec.rz
302 Moved Temporarily
GET http://bb-m.rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/rack-test-0.6.2.gemspec.rz
200 OK
GET http://rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/journey-1.0.4.gemspec.rz
302 Moved Temporarily
GET http://production.cf.rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/journey-1.0.4.gemspec.rz
200 OK
GET http://rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/sprockets-2.1.3.gemspec.rz
302 Moved Temporarily
GET http://production.cf.rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/sprockets-2.1.3.gemspec.rz
200 OK
GET http://rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/erubis-2.7.0.gemspec.rz
302 Moved Temporarily
GET http://production.cf.rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/erubis-2.7.0.gemspec.rz
200 OK
GET http://rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/arel-3.0.2.gemspec.rz
302 Moved Temporarily
GET http://production.cf.rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/arel-3.0.2.gemspec.rz
200 OK
GET http://rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/tzinfo-0.3.29.gemspec.rz
302 Moved Temporarily
GET http://production.cf.rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/tzinfo-0.3.29.gemspec.rz
200 OK
GET http://rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/tzinfo-0.3.30.gemspec.rz
302 Moved Temporarily
GET http://production.cf.rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/tzinfo-0.3.30.gemspec.rz
200 OK
GET http://rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/tzinfo-0.3.31.gemspec.rz
302 Moved Temporarily
GET http://bb-m.rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/tzinfo-0.3.31.gemspec.rz
200 OK
GET http://rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/tzinfo-0.3.32.gemspec.rz
302 Moved Temporarily
GET http://production.cf.rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/tzinfo-0.3.32.gemspec.rz
200 OK
GET http://rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/tzinfo-0.3.33.gemspec.rz
302 Moved Temporarily
GET http://production.cf.rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/tzinfo-0.3.33.gemspec.rz
200 OK
GET http://rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/tzinfo-0.3.34.gemspec.rz
302 Moved Temporarily
GET http://production.cf.rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/tzinfo-0.3.34.gemspec.rz
200 OK
GET http://rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/mail-2.4.4.gemspec.rz
302 Moved Temporarily
GET http://production.cf.rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/mail-2.4.4.gemspec.rz
200 OK
GET http://rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/rake-0.9.2.2.gemspec.rz
302 Moved Temporarily
GET http://bb-m.rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/rake-0.9.2.2.gemspec.rz
200 OK
GET http://rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/rack-ssl-1.3.2.gemspec.rz
302 Moved Temporarily
GET http://production.cf.rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/rack-ssl-1.3.2.gemspec.rz
200 OK
GET http://rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/thor-0.14.6.gemspec.rz
302 Moved Temporarily
GET http://bb-m.rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/thor-0.14.6.gemspec.rz
200 OK
GET http://rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/thor-0.15.0.gemspec.rz
302 Moved Temporarily
GET http://bb-m.rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/thor-0.15.0.gemspec.rz
200 OK
GET http://rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/thor-0.15.1.gemspec.rz
302 Moved Temporarily
GET http://production.cf.rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/thor-0.15.1.gemspec.rz
200 OK
GET http://rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/thor-0.15.2.gemspec.rz
302 Moved Temporarily
GET http://production.cf.rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/thor-0.15.2.gemspec.rz
200 OK
GET http://rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/thor-0.15.3.gemspec.rz
302 Moved Temporarily
GET http://production.cf.rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/thor-0.15.3.gemspec.rz
200 OK
GET http://rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/thor-0.15.4.gemspec.rz
302 Moved Temporarily
GET http://production.cf.rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/thor-0.15.4.gemspec.rz
200 OK
GET http://rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/thor-0.16.0.gemspec.rz
302 Moved Temporarily
GET http://production.cf.rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/thor-0.16.0.gemspec.rz
200 OK
GET http://rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/rdoc-3.4.gemspec.rz
302 Moved Temporarily
GET http://production.cf.rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/rdoc-3.4.gemspec.rz
200 OK
GET http://rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/rdoc-3.5.gemspec.rz
302 Moved Temporarily
GET http://production.cf.rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/rdoc-3.5.gemspec.rz
200 OK
GET http://rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/rdoc-3.5.1.gemspec.rz
302 Moved Temporarily
GET http://production.cf.rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/rdoc-3.5.1.gemspec.rz
200 OK
GET http://rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/rdoc-3.5.2.gemspec.rz
302 Moved Temporarily
GET http://production.cf.rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/rdoc-3.5.2.gemspec.rz
200 OK
GET http://rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/rdoc-3.5.3.gemspec.rz
302 Moved Temporarily
GET http://bb-m.rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/rdoc-3.5.3.gemspec.rz
200 OK
GET http://rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/rdoc-3.6.gemspec.rz
302 Moved Temporarily
GET http://production.cf.rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/rdoc-3.6.gemspec.rz
200 OK
GET http://rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/rdoc-3.6.1.gemspec.rz
302 Moved Temporarily
GET http://production.cf.rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/rdoc-3.6.1.gemspec.rz
200 OK
GET http://rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/rdoc-3.7.gemspec.rz
302 Moved Temporarily
GET http://production.cf.rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/rdoc-3.7.gemspec.rz
200 OK
GET http://rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/rdoc-3.8.gemspec.rz
302 Moved Temporarily
GET http://bb-m.rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/rdoc-3.8.gemspec.rz
200 OK
GET http://rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/rdoc-3.9.gemspec.rz
302 Moved Temporarily
GET http://production.cf.rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/rdoc-3.9.gemspec.rz
200 OK
GET http://rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/rdoc-3.9.1.gemspec.rz
302 Moved Temporarily
GET http://production.cf.rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/rdoc-3.9.1.gemspec.rz
200 OK
GET http://rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/rdoc-3.9.2.gemspec.rz
302 Moved Temporarily
GET http://production.cf.rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/rdoc-3.9.2.gemspec.rz
200 OK
GET http://rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/rdoc-3.9.3.gemspec.rz
302 Moved Temporarily
GET http://production.cf.rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/rdoc-3.9.3.gemspec.rz
200 OK
GET http://rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/rdoc-3.9.4.gemspec.rz
302 Moved Temporarily
GET http://bb-m.rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/rdoc-3.9.4.gemspec.rz
200 OK
GET http://rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/rdoc-3.10.gemspec.rz
302 Moved Temporarily
GET http://production.cf.rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/rdoc-3.10.gemspec.rz
200 OK
GET http://rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/rdoc-3.11.gemspec.rz
302 Moved Temporarily
GET http://production.cf.rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/rdoc-3.11.gemspec.rz
200 OK
GET http://rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/rdoc-3.12.gemspec.rz
302 Moved Temporarily
GET http://production.cf.rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/rdoc-3.12.gemspec.rz
200 OK
```

and it kept going. How can I install ruby on rails onto my server? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have root access on the machine?

If so, you may be able to make your installation smoother by installing each native gems as the root user. This is because the native gem is needing to compile code on the server.

Warning: this is not exactly secure, so don't do it on a high security production server.

Here are ones I do, and you can pick and choose whichever you want:

```
sudo su
gem install bcrypt-ruby
gem install curb
gem install fastthread
gem install ffi 
gem install json 
gem install mysql2
gem install nokogiri
gem install pg
gem install rmagick
gem install ruby-prof
gem install sqlite3 
gem install ssh
gem install therubyracer
```

You may also want to try using a ruby installation tool. My favorite is rbenv: https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv

Answer (score 0):

try this way, go into the source and:

```
cd ruby-1.9.2-p136/ext/zlib/
ruby extconf.rb --with-zlib-include=/usr/include --width-zlib-lib=/usr/lib
gem install rails --include-dependencies
```

Comment: I tried entering what you told me and this is what I got 
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
`ERROR:  Error installing rails:
 ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.`

        `/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/ruby.h`


`Gem files will remain installed in /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.7.5 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.7.5/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out`